# The words go marching round and round

Tags: crosswords

Here's another variety crossword type: Marching Bands

### Rules

- Words *march* across each line. Each line has 2 words of variable length. The two words will fill up the whole line.

  - Line 6's words are 5 letters each - they don't go through the black box.
- Words circle in each *band*. Each band's words are entered clockwise, one word after another, with clues given in order. The words together will fill up the band.
- All words are at least 3 letters long, and all are in dictionary.com except for the abbreviation and the phrase

[image: 11x11 grid]

(For those who have trouble with pictures: the grid is 11x11. The center square is blacked out. The rows are numbered 1-11 from top to bottom. Nested bands are lettered A-E from outside in)

Clues:

```
Bands
A
1. Uplifting song
2. Border-checking officials
3. Traveled over ice, perhaps
4. Paper prep place
5. Spiritual force
6. "Survivor"'s network (abbr)
7. Irish fairy queen
B
1. Idealized small town
2. Representative
3. Centers of infection
4. Small trace
5. Spiritual teacher
6. Acid used in vegetable oil
C
1. Center
2. Mythological blood
3. Installment
4. Took (a test)
5. Watery protection
D
1. Leftover
2. Search through
3. Lots and lots
E
1. Quite angry

Marchers
1
a) Crumb carrying insect
b) Garment's lower edges
2
a) Hannibal's surname
b) Crown
3
a) Deep hurt
b) Piece of writing
4
a) British bishop's hat
b) Mossy-like plant
5
a) Sailor's punny goodbye (2 wrds)
b) British hooligans
6
a) Light-haired
b) Country-like
7
a) Comets' heads
b) Egg, perhaps
8
a) Good-smelling spice
b) Excited
9
a) Wipe
b) Administering medication 
10
a) Thief
b) Diaper, informally
11
a) Lets go
b) Meander
```

Feedback is appreciated :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

Clue answers:

> [image]

Comment: I think in the clue answers `2. representative` is missing 2 letters.