# The Cryptic Cat strikes again! (2 Marching Bands)

Tags: word, cryptic-clues, crosswords

Conversation with the Cryptic Cat after my [last crossword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/100027):

> **Cat:** WHERE WERE THE CRYPTIC CLUES
> **Me:** Calm down! I just wanted to make a normal-
> **Cat:** Normal? What’s the point of a *normal* crossword? Cryptics are the way to go.
> **Me:** Okay, okay, I’ll put some cryptics in my next one. Thing is, I want to make another Marching Bands, and they’re completely checked, and I hear you’re not supposed to do that in cryptics, so-
> **Cat:** You talk too much. Just put clues along the diagonals! Easy peasy*
> **Cat:** Also, the cryptics should solve to my favorite things: ***** ******.

<sub>*It turns out that this is *not* easy. Please forgive the grids and clues! They’re as good as I could make them under this constraint. The wordplay is legal, I promise.</sub>

Here are the rules of Marching Bands crosswords, rewritten for your convenience:

- Words *march* across each line. Each line has 2 words of variable length. The two words will fill up the whole line.

  - Line 6's words are 5 letters each - they don't go through the black box.
- Words circle in each *band*. Each band's words are entered clockwise, one word after another, with clues given in order. The words together will fill up the band.
- All words are at least 3 letters long.

So I went off, made the cryptics, made the grids, made the clues. Then that incorrigible Cat came in and **scrambled them!** Each *group* of clues is in the right place - both of the Band A clue sets should be placed in the outer layer a grid - but sometimes the clues for grid #1 comes first, and sometimes the clues for grid #2 comes first. The only set of clues that is guaranteed to be the right way around (grid #1 before #2) is Marchers-1.

To recap: the clues below are in scrambled order, but are in the correct groups nonetheless. The two solved grids will have cryptic clues read down the diagonals (left-to-right, then right-to-left, so \/). These clues will solve into a two-word phrase (one word per grid) that is the answer to the question *“What are the Cryptic Cat’s favorite things? (5, 6)”*. Feel free to ask for clarifications if that explanation didn't make sense.

The grids:

[image: 11x11 grid] [image: 11x11 grid]

For those who have trouble with pictures: the grids are 11x11, with rows labeled 1-11 from top to bottom, and the circular bands labeled A-E going inwards. Each long diagonal is shaded, and the central square is black.

#### Marchers

**1.**
*a)* Sharp, pungent flavor
*b)* Country in the middle of South Africa

*a)* Constrictors, sometimes
*b)* Stinging sensations

**2.**
*a)* Sparkling new
*b)* Lures

*a)* Musical rates
*b)* Give in

**3.**
*a)* Holder of merit badges
*b)* Away from shelter

*a)* Cold Italian desserts
*b)* Popular snack during sports games

**4.**
*a)* Dietary fiber
*b)* Character often used as digital eyes

*a)* Ancient city on the Gulf of Aqaba
*b)* 14-line poem

**5.**
*a)* Fixes with thread
*b)* Open with key

*a)* Assign a new value to
*b)* "Bad" cholesterol (abbr.)

**6.**
*a)* Scatter carelessly
*b)* Place of entertaining battles

*a)* Promises openly
*b)* Wind around and around

**7.**
*a)* Bug B Gon manufacturer
*b)* Proclaim far and wide

*a)* Expressively flexible tempo
*b)* Jail, informally

**8.**
*a)* Remedy
*b)* Small, sparkly crown

*a)* Off the mark
*b)* Pencil shadings

**9.**
*a)* At which, in legalese
*b)* Singular friend (2 wrds.)

*a)* Interjection of contempt
*b)* Woman bequeathed to

**10.**
*a)* Barcelona bloom
*b)* Put back

*a)* Responsibilities
*b)* Small coin from olden Finland

**11.**
*a)* Old Russian leader
*b)* Less potent form of estrogen

*a)* Someone who cries feebly
*b)* Israeli submachine gun

#### Bands

**A.**
*1)* Showing off
*2)* Chunk of learning
*3)* Tools of opening
*4)* Sudden attack of illness
*5)* Jean-making Strauss
*6)* Bank's bouncing explanation (abbr.)
*7)* Model

*1)* Knotty mess
*2)* Chronic drinker
*3)* Hilton, say
*4)* Group of connected computers (abbr.)
*5)* Someone not from here
*6)* Little crumb
*7)* Fluids used in vaccines
*8)* Pack away
*9)* What sinking ships broadcast
*10)* Calm

**B.**
*1)* Domain across the seas
*2)* Gave
*3)* Opposite of and
*4)* Frank diary writer
*5)* Notes after email signoffs (abbr.)
*6)* Without damage
*7)* Reading & writing (abbr.)

*1)* Purpose
*2)* Popular sport in Canada (2 wrds.)
*3)* Trophy of war
*4)* Weasley family owl
*5)* Canadian physicist/politician Ted
*6)* Barn's direction topper

**C.**
*1)* TYPE LIKE THIS
*2)* Furtive walk
*3)* Mexican revolutionary
*4)* Standing quite straight
*5)* Suggested vitamin intake (abbr.)

*1)* Hispanic lady
*2)* Cover
*3)* Residence of a raptor
*4)* Blast
*5)* Famous Irish king named Brian

**D.**
*1)* First Republican president
*2)* Wild indulgence
*3)* Celtic god of the dead

*1)* Seat fit for a monarch
*2)* Italy's version of the BBC (abbr.)
*3)* Reverse of an iamb

**E.**
*1)* Actor's last act (2 wrds.)

*1)* Solar storms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The filled grids:

> [image]

The diagonals spell

> "Test flip neon innocent" and "Bills precise controls".
>
>  The first is a clue for GREEN: "test" is GRE, and "flip neon" gives the reverse of NE. Combined, these make GREEN, defined by "innocent".
>
>  "Bills precise controls" is a double definition: "bills" and "precise controls" both define CHECKS.
>
>  So, Cryptic Cat's favorite things are **GREEN CHECKS**!

Complete list of clue answers and assignments to grids:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

## Wrap-up:  The Making Of *The Cryptic Cat strikes again!*

*This is not a solution to the puzzle, but provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been [approved by the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/).*

***Caution:** This post contains ALL the spoilers.*

---

#### Inspiration

I like variety crosswords grids. In a [previous post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100027/the-words-go-marching-round-and-round) I tried out a new kind, called Marching Bands, where the words went in circles and lines. That one had such good reception that I decided to make another. There would be a gimmick (I *love* gimmicks - see earlier note on variety crosswords), and I decided that I wanted to work in cryptic clues somehow.

#### Creative steps

Now I had to figure how exactly to incorporate cryptics into a Marching Bands. My thought process went exactly as the "conversation" between me and the Cryptic Cat is written at the start of the question. Since the phrase I wanted to clue had 2 words, I split the crossword into two grids. An obvious extra gimmick now was to mix the clues for the grids up.

#### Logistical steps

I worked on this puzzle in 4 sections: making the first grid, making the second grid, cluing the grids, and formatting. Note that all the pictures in this section are taken from my Google Sheet's version history. I also haven't pictured the completed grids, as you can see them in the Resources section.

**Making the first grid**

First, I had to choose which word of my final phrase (GREEN CHECKS) this grid would have a cryptic clue for. I went with CHECKS because it was an obvious ddef. Google was my friend here - I took some of its suggested synonyms as inspiration. I tried various words, but I kept having problems with E1 having a legal word with 4 out of 8 letters forced. Below is an example where I finally got a legal E1, but I didn't think the first row could feasibly end in an F.

[image: BILLS OR CONFIRMATIONS]

After [confirmation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54986251#54986251) that padding with an adjective was legal, I played around with various synonyms for each of my words until I landed on a set with a decent surface and the right number of letters.

As the first step of making a Marching Bands, I played around with various 4-letter words starting with B which themselves started longer words. Eventually I found 4 words that worked for the first row's Marchers and the first two A Bands words. I worked my way down a few Bands' top rows, then resolved the section in the middle-right of the grid. I dropped ICE HOCKEY at this point as a word to build off. On the left side of the grid I dropped VAN GOGH. I got sooo close to completing, and then... **disaster**. Awhile back I had accidentally changed one of my "locked-in" letters that was meant for the cryptic clue.

[image: mistake]

I've screenshotted the mistake-grid as an example of how you can get quite into a grid with a mistake. In the forth row, the I in IRON has to be an O to allow CONTROLS. Here you can also see my marking system in action. Blue = start of a Bands word, orange = start of a Marchers word.

This resulted in much cursing, followed by deleting a bunch of work and re-gridding. This time I managed to close off the grid, using much of the same techniques.

**Making the second grid**

This cryptic clue took *so long* to make. I mean *so long*. First I had to figure out how to clue GREEN. My initial idea was extracting from G?R?E?E?N, or something of the like. I couldn't find any phrases that worked - one day down the drain! Then I spent several days trying different combinations of charades - GR + E + EN, G(RE)EN, etc. When I finally hit upon the idea to do G + RE + EN, it still took a day of fiddling.

I did the same starting-a-Marching-Bands steps outlined above. I worked down around the right, then down the left, then across the bottom… and then I got stuck. And I mean **stuck**. After 3 days of making no progress, and seeing letters float behind my eyelids, I took a cooling-off period. A solid week of not gridding.

[image: backup point]

Above you can see where I got stuck. When I came back, I decided to do the unthinkable: completely start over. I deleted all of my work on the second grid, deleted my cryptic clue, and started making another. Before, I hadn’t considered reversals, so I put on in this time - GRE + EN<. I was fairly satisfied with the surface (I mean, it wasn’t great, but I took the 20-letter limit into account.) Time to re-grid!

What surprised me was how quick this grid came together. I had a very few dead ends. The parts of C1 and D1 I would need to use for those row’s initial Marchers were common word endings - I didn’t have to worry about that side too much! Though this time around I wasn’t able to fit as many long words in, all the ones I put in were at least decent. I did make a mistake in the bottom-right corner, but I’ll cover that later in this post (see Evolution).

**Making the clues**

First I copied all the words from the grids into neat little columns in my Google Sheet. Then I checked that they were all spelled correctly from the grid. Then I checked again. Once I was fairly confident that I had the right words, I started cluing. I mostly just worked down my columns, but I skipped some words that were harder to clue for later. Then I checked each clue for part-of-speech/pluralization mismatches. Then I checked for correct spelling again. Then I checked the clues for mismatches again. I’m noting all of these double-checks here to make it more clear how silly I felt when Deus pointed out the corner mistake.

**Formatting**

I drafted out an approximate story in a Google Doc. then started copy-pasting my clues over. I decided the spacing I wanted, what I wanted bold or italicized, the format my numbers would be in… there’s a lot of choices when formatting clues! This was also the step that I randomized clue order, by generating a random sequence of 1s and 2s to determine which grid’s clues came first.
Then I doubled-checked all the clues again, copied the draft into PSE’s “Ask Question”, looked over for formatting… and hit Post!

#### Resources

For tracking the growing grids and clues, I had a massive Google Sheet. Below is a zoomed-out picture of the final grid (with the corner inconsistency still in). Note that not all the clues are pictured, as they went for quite a bit off the bottom of the screen.

[image: google sheet]

For forcing the cryptics to be the proper length, I used [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/) and Wikipedia's [list of charade clues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossword_abbreviations).

For gridding, I used [onelook](https://onelook.com) for finding words that would fit. I often had multiple onelook windows up at the same time, cross-referencing possibilities to see if any would work together.

For creating the crosswords clues, I used wordplay.com's [answer-clue lookup](https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-clues) to get ideas for clues.

#### Evolution

Deusovi found an error in the corner of the puzzle. If you look at the Google Sheet, in the bottom-right corner of the top grid the word "ALIEC" appears. I had meant for this to be "ALICE". Somehow, this typo survived 3 separate rounds of double-checking. I took his [suggestion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=55471031#55471031) to re-grid with ALIEN and shifted around the necessary words. The new 11B for that area is one I wouldn't use normally (too science-y), but desperate times called for desperate measures. Yes, I'm calling a small error in a crossword grid a "desperate time" :P.

I also messed up on the direction to read the cryptics in - they go \/, not /\, as the original post said.

#### Your thoughts/mental process

*Below is an approximate transcript of my thoughts*

> THIS IS SO HARD WHY AM I EVEN TRYING
> ...oh wait if I use these words, then that area is resolved.
> Okay, let's put a long word here to build off
> AHH THERE ARE NO LONG WORDS THAT WORK
> Oh no, I changed one of the cryptic clue letters... have to re-grid that whole area
> What if I run a word here?
> This word and this word and this word work together, but then that word’s ending doesn’t work… AHH WHY IS THIS SO HARD

And repeat.

<sub>I may have taken this suggested heading a bit too literally</sub>

#### Takeaway

My main takeaway from this puzzle is that working under tight constraints can be fun... once you get past the problems that those constraints offer. When I finally 20-letter cryptic clues that were both valid and allowed for clue-able E1s, there was much rejoicing. The long time period spent messing with the cryptics before that? Much head-banging.

Another important practice when working with large puzzles is carefully tracking what is done so far. I did this with color-coded grid cells (as you can see above).

To avoid making mistakes with large puzzles I **highly** recommend getting a test-solver. I don’t know anyone willing to test-solve my crosswords, but they would’ve caught my errors.

And of course, the most important factor in making a large puzzle: when you get stuck, take a break. My brain was just unable to work on the old grid #2, so I changed the grid. *We care more about quality than the number of puzzles per (insert arbitrary time unit).*

I would suggest that if anyone wants to make a puzzle with extracted cryptic clues, that using an extraction mechanism with a more flexible letter count is a good thing. There was much hardship in this puzzle associated just with forcing cryptics to conform to my 20-letters-long constraint.

Plus, Deusovi pointed out how some of my clues were a weensy (read: lot) [illegal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55471884#55471884)

Comment: Feel free to edit this - I'm sure there are still some grammar errors left in it.

Comment: Very much agreed on (at least) two things: (1) constrained puzzle-making is very fun (and leads to more rewarding puzzles), but also very difficult, and (2) length-constrained cryptic clues are hard to write!

Comment: `This resulted in much cursing` happens sometimes